# Does Singapore Airlines offer free multi-day stopovers?

Tags: singapore-airlines

Does Singapore Airlines offer free multi-day stopovers in Singapore if you're transiting through it on your normal flights, or do you have to purchase individual flights?

They appear to have some package deals for single night stopovers but these are both non-free and too short.

Comment: According to [multiple](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/flights/2014/05/29/free-stopover-flight/9676293/) [sources](http://www.hopper.com/articles/1048/get-free-international-stopovers-on-these-airlines), yes.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you may be conflating two different things here.

Singapore Airlines offers "[Singapore Stopover Holidays](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/special-offers/singapore-stopover-holiday/)" to passengers transiting Singapore on Singapore Airlines flights only.  These include hotel nights and airport transfers and are *not* free, although you usually get a good deal on the rates.

They also offers "free" stopovers in Singapore, which means that if it costs you (say) $2000 to fly London-Singapore-Sydney direct, you can add a break of a few days and still pay the same $2000.  But in this scenario, hotels and transportation are your own problem.

Comment: The latter is what I'm interested in.  I haven't been able to confirm that they do actually allow a break of more than one day.

Comment: @dlanod Have you tried searching on ITA Matrix and pulling up the exact fare conditions?  They'll have the stopover rules.  IIRC you can get these on the SQ site as well, although I haven't used it since the last revamp.